# How to read data from excel file without passing bytes to read_excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

Error:

```
FutureWarning: Passing bytes to 'read_excel' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To read from a byte string, wrap it in a `BytesIO` object.
  df = pd.read_excel(blob_data.readall(), engine='openpyxl')
```

I am getting this error, Any other option to read data from excel file?

I want alternate solution or library support for this openpyxl issue!

Answer (score 0):

`blob_data.readall()` are bytes, and passing bytes to `pandas.read_excel` is deprecated.

You can pass not bytes but file-like object using `BytesIO`:

```py
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(blob_data.readall()), engine='openpyxl')
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrap your byte data in a `BytesIO` object, which acts like a file-like object and can be used with `read_excel` without triggering the deprecation warning.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

# Assuming blob_data is a bytes object containing the Excel file content

df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(blob_data), engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: But now I am getting df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(blob_data), engine='openpyxl')
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'StorageStreamDownloader' error.

Comment: Actually I am storing excel sheet onto Azure Blob service and then fetch that file and using that Blob_data here using  blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()